# How to register name and log in my solana token on GITHUB

Tags: registry, token, solana

I was trying to registry my token on solana blockchain  but when I arrived to step on GITHUB (((token-list))) I found it had been archived SO I can not pull a request to add my file on repository
if someone know how to solve the problem pleas assist

Answer (score 0):

So recently, about 2 weeks ago, Solana token list stopped accepting tokens through pull request.

If you want to add a name or logo to your SPL TOKEN, you can check out [this video](https://youtu.be/DQbt0-riooo) on YouTube which explains it clearly on how to do it through the Metaplex Standard.